# M.E.A.N. mongoose and passport js? Basic guide needed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

Installed [M.E.A.N framework](http://mean.io/#!/) on ubuntu 14.04

I have basic knowledge of Angular, mongoDB,  node js but not with express

**localhost:3000/** is working fine , landing page appears

I want to use [mongoose](https://hackhands.com/mongodb-crud-mvc-way-with-passport-authentication/) and [passport.js](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) for user authentication?

Means where do we authenticate user? where are the database?

I have read many documentation but didn't get the initial stage where to head start as everything.

on mongoose documentation  it was written to run below URL

mongodb://localhost/todos

but it doesn't work either.

Please guide me a little bit

Comment: Is it too broad to close?

Answer (score 2):

You should follow -

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Tutorial for the above. I learned about all of the above as you mentioned from the tutorial.

Hope, this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: that tutorial is very good and informative. Thanks. but I have installed MEAN , see my file structure http://i.imgur.com/3lwu45c.png

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to learn from scratch, look at an implementation using all of those components mongo,node,express and passport. One of the best examples that I have found is the [MEAN.IO](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) repo that has full on auth with third party providers and local strategies.

If you are bit more advance then I would recommend you to check out my [LearnMEAN](http://learnmean.com/) tutorial.